# Android list with button

Tags: java, android, button, textview, adapter

I have seen a tutorial (on youtube) to create a list with button in Android, this is my code:

```
package com.example.giacomob.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Giacomo B on 05/08/2015.
 */
public class Page1 extends Activity {
   // private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    final int n_campi = 8; //definisco la costante del numero di campi per fermata
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

        // String dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1");
        //Intent intent = getIntent(); // Point 1
        // Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // Point 2
        // String data1 = bundle.getString("NomeDati1"); // Point 3
        String dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1"); //preleva la stringa
        Toast.makeText(this, dato1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //PROVA: questo mi fa comparire una specie di label notifica trasparente con il valore di "data1"
        Log.d("TAG", "data1:" + dato1); //credo sia una specie di debug

        // seconda stringa
        String destination_nf =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("Destinazione_scelta");
        String destination_f = destination_nf.trim(); //tolgo gli spazi a inzio e fine
        String destination = destination_f.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + destination_f.substring(1,destination_f.length()).toLowerCase(); //Faccio in modo che l'utente mi passi una stringa con prima maiuscola e le altre minuscole
        Toast.makeText(this, destination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        //    String salve =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("ciao");

        int c=0, j=0, n=0;
        boolean verify = false;

        //FARE CONTROLLO IN CASO IL FILE XML E' VUOTO E QUINDI LA STRINGA E' VUOTA
        String[] arr = dato1.split("\\|");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " => " + arr[i]);
        }
        final ArrayList<String> listp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=3; i<arr.length-1; i=i+n_campi) {

            if(arr[i].equals(destination)) {
                System.out.println(i + " des " + arr[i]);
                for(; j<n_campi+c; j++)
                    if(j==0+c) {
                        n++;
                        listp.add("Informazioni fermata numero " +n);
                        listp.add("Coordinata X: " + arr[j]);
                    }
                    else if(j==1+c)
                        listp.add("Coordinata Y: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==2+c)
                        listp.add("Nazione di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==3+c)
                        listp.add("Paese di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==4+c)
                        listp.add("Via di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==5+c)
                        listp.add("Id Corriera: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==6+c)
                        listp.add("Paese Fermata: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==7+c) {
                        listp.add("Via fermata: " + arr[j]);
                        listp.add("   ");
                    }
                    /*switch(j)
                    {
                        case(0):
                            listp.add("Coordinata X" + arr[j]);
                        case(1):
                            listp.add("Coordinata Y" + arr[j]);
                        case(2):
                            listp.add("Nazione di destinazine" + arr[j]);
                        case(3):
                            listp.add("Paese di destinazione" + arr[j]);
                        case(4):
                            listp.add("Via di destinazione" + arr[j]);
                        case(5):
                            listp.add("Id Corriera" + arr[j]);
                        case(6):
                            listp.add("Paese Fermata" + arr[j]);
                        case(7):
                            listp.add("Via fermataX" + arr[j]);
                    }*/
                   // listp.add(arr[j]);    // in questo modo, recupero la lista nel layout solo se è presente una corrispondenza tra paese nel file XML e in quello fornito dall'utente
                    verify = true;

            }
            else
            {
                j=j+n_campi;
            }

            c = j;
        }
        if(verify == false)
            Toast.makeText(this,"Non sono stati trovati mezzi per " + destination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      /*  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            listp.add(arr[i]);
        }*/
        // recupero la lista dal layout
        final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // creo e istruisco l'adattatore
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listp);


        // inietto i dati
       // mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

        mylist.setAdapter(new MyListAdaper(this, R.layout.activity_page1, adapter));


        Button b_load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send2);
        b_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent openTrack = new Intent(Page1.this, Track.class);

                //String ciao = "ahahah";
                //String data1 = ReadXMLFile.readXMLFile(Page1.this);
                openTrack.putExtra("Destination", getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1"));
                startActivity(openTrack);

            }
        });

    }

    private class MyListAdaper extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private int layout;



        public MyListAdaper(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null ){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         //       viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail)
                viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textList);
                viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
                viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bottone cliccato" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }

                                                     });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        //ImageView  thumbnail; //forse non serve
        TextView title;
        Button button;
    }
    }
```

the problem born when I insert the Array in the adapter, in this line:

```
 mylist.setAdapter(new MyListAdaper(this, R.layout.activity_page1, adapter));
```

the problem is in adapter, in fact if I create a line such as:

```
private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and I insert "data" in place of "adapter", there are no errors. But as I implemented the code I need to insert "adapter".
The significant code is on bottom:

```
  private class MyListAdaper extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private int layout;



        public MyListAdaper(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null ){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         //       viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail)
                viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textList);
                viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
                viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bottone cliccato" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }

                                                     });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        //ImageView  thumbnail; //forse non serve
        TextView title;
        Button button;
    }
```

How can I do? I must modify "adapter" or the class MyListAdapter?

This is my XML file called activity_page_1:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/string_destination"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="359dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textList"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list_item_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        />

    

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string_loadfermata"
        android:id="@+id/button_send2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have this problem beacause first I had create the list without buttons, after I insert the button and the class "myListAdapter"

Last update:

```html
package com.example.giacomob.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Giacomo B on 05/08/2015.
 */
public class Page1 extends Activity {
   // private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    final int n_campi = 8; //definisco la costante del numero di campi per fermata
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page1);

        // String dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1");
        //Intent intent = getIntent(); // Point 1
        // Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); // Point 2
        // String data1 = bundle.getString("NomeDati1"); // Point 3
        String dato1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1"); //preleva la stringa
        Toast.makeText(this, dato1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //PROVA: questo mi fa comparire una specie di label notifica trasparente con il valore di "data1"
        Log.d("TAG", "data1:" + dato1); //credo sia una specie di debug

        // seconda stringa
        String destination_nf =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("Destinazione_scelta");
        String destination_f = destination_nf.trim(); //tolgo gli spazi a inzio e fine
        String destination = destination_f.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + destination_f.substring(1,destination_f.length()).toLowerCase(); //Faccio in modo che l'utente mi passi una stringa con prima maiuscola e le altre minuscole
        Toast.makeText(this, destination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



        //    String salve =  getIntent().getExtras().getString("ciao");

        int c=0, j=0, n=0;
        boolean verify = false;

        //FARE CONTROLLO IN CASO IL FILE XML E' VUOTO E QUINDI LA STRINGA E' VUOTA
        String[] arr = dato1.split("\\|");
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " => " + arr[i]);
        }
        final ArrayList<String> listp = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=3; i<arr.length-1; i=i+n_campi) {

            if(arr[i].equals(destination)) {
                System.out.println(i + " des " + arr[i]);
                for(; j<n_campi+c; j++)
                    if(j==0+c) {
                        n++;
                        listp.add("Informazioni fermata numero " +n);
                        listp.add("Coordinata X: " + arr[j]);
                    }
                    else if(j==1+c)
                        listp.add("Coordinata Y: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==2+c)
                        listp.add("Nazione di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==3+c)
                        listp.add("Paese di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==4+c)
                        listp.add("Via di destinazione: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==5+c)
                        listp.add("Id Corriera: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==6+c)
                        listp.add("Paese Fermata: " + arr[j]);
                    else if (j==7+c) {
                        listp.add("Via fermata: " + arr[j]);
                        listp.add("   ");
                    }
                    /*switch(j)
                    {
                        case(0):
                            listp.add("Coordinata X" + arr[j]);
                        case(1):
                            listp.add("Coordinata Y" + arr[j]);
                        case(2):
                            listp.add("Nazione di destinazine" + arr[j]);
                        case(3):
                            listp.add("Paese di destinazione" + arr[j]);
                        case(4):
                            listp.add("Via di destinazione" + arr[j]);
                        case(5):
                            listp.add("Id Corriera" + arr[j]);
                        case(6):
                            listp.add("Paese Fermata" + arr[j]);
                        case(7):
                            listp.add("Via fermataX" + arr[j]);
                    }*/
                   // listp.add(arr[j]);    // in questo modo, recupero la lista nel layout solo se è presente una corrispondenza tra paese nel file XML e in quello fornito dall'utente
                    verify = true;

            }
            else
            {
                j=j+n_campi;
            }

            c = j;
        }
        if(verify == false)
            Toast.makeText(this,"Non sono stati trovati mezzi per " + destination, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


      /*  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            listp.add(arr[i]);
        }*/
        // recupero la lista dal layout
        final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // creo e istruisco l'adattatore
      //  final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listp);
      //  final ListView a = (ListView) adapter;

        // inietto i dati
     //   mylist.setAdapter(adapter);

        mylist.setAdapter(new MyListAdaper(this, R.layout.activity_page1, listp));


        Button b_load = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send2);
        b_load.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent openTrack = new Intent(Page1.this, Track.class);

                //String ciao = "ahahah";
                //String data1 = ReadXMLFile.readXMLFile(Page1.this);
                openTrack.putExtra("Destination", getIntent().getExtras().getString("NomeDati1"));
                startActivity(openTrack);

            }
        });

    }

    private class MyListAdaper extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private int layout;



        public MyListAdaper(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if(convertView == null ){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
         //       viewHolder.thumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_thumbnail)
                //viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cazzo);
                //viewHolder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_btn);
                viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Bottone cliccato" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        }

                                                     });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else {
                mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
            }

            return convertView;
        }

    }
    public class ViewHolder {
        //ImageView  thumbnail; //forse non serve
        TextView title;
        Button button;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Try to look at this blog I wrote sometime back about [handling clicks in listview](http://blog.antrromet.com/2013/07/handling-clicks-within-list-items-in.html).

Comment: thanks @Antrromet, I will Look this code tomorrow. In my country is too late now, and I need to go to sleep. Thanks. If I reply problems, can I write Tomorrow some question to you about this?

Comment: @Heyyou , the problem is that I can't insert ad ArrayAdapter because in the constructor need a List.. How I can do?

Comment: @Heyyou my list works..but I would to insert the button for each element, I would to understand what I need to insert in my constructor.. How I change my ArrayAdapter to a List?

Comment: @Heyyou Done! :) I have update my question

Comment: @Heyyou I have modified my code, now it works, but there are a problem: I would to show a button for each list..in this way the app show me a button AND A TEXTBOX WITH THE TITLE togheter for each list. I would to show the textbox with the title only one time. Now I update my question with the new code :) thanks Heyyou, look it when you have the time :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because you only have a constructor for your `MyListAdaper` as following:

```
public MyListAdaper(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects)
```

Please note that the third argument is a **List**, not an **ArrayAdapter**.  Your code:

```
final ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listp);
mylist.setAdapter(new MyListAdaper(this, R.layout.activity_page1, adapter));
```

You see you assign the `adapter` (**ArrayAdapter**) to a **List**.  So you got problems.

If you really want to do this, please create a new constructor for your `MyListAdaper`, as:

```
public MyListAdaper(Context context, int resource, ArrayAdapter<String> objects)
```

Although I don't think it's necessary.  And from your code, I don't think you need to do this.  Normally passing a list of data (for example, the `List<String>`) to the adapter is enough.

---

I also realized that you had some issues which will not cause compile errors, but may not what you want, for example, you can't put:

```
mainViewHolder.title.setText(getItem(position));
```

to the `else` braces.  If you really want to show the item no. to each row, you need to put it out of `if` and `else`.

You may need to have a look at several more tutorial of `ListView`, such as:

[Android ListView Tutorial for beginners](http://www.codelearn.org/android-tutorial/android-listview)

[Android ListView Advanced Tutorial but useful](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/)

Hope this will help.